# How can I do if elif and else in case?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a spanish voice assistant. I don't know how create a case with `if`, `elif` and `else`.

```
    if texto == nada:
      engine.say("Ok estare para  ti cuando me necesites")
      engine.runAndWait()
      
    elif texto == notenecesito:
      engine.say("Ok estare para  ti cuando me necesites")
      engine.runAndWait()
    elif texto == lahora:
      engine.say("La hora es"+ current_time)
      engine.runAndWait()
      print(Fore.RED+current_time)
    else:
      engine.say("buscando " + texto ,"Abriendo el navegador")
      engine.runAndWait()
      webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+texto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have indentation error in your code. There's no switch in python so you have to use if-elif-else to do so. If you want you can create a function which will work as switch case. Like this:

```
def switch(texto):
    if texto == "nada":
        engine.say("Ok estare para  ti cuando me necesites")
        engine.runAndWait()
      
    elif texto == "notenecesito":
        engine.say("Ok estare para  ti cuando me necesites")
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif texto == "lahora":
        engine.say("La hora es"+ current_time)
        engine.runAndWait()
        print(Fore.RED+current_time)
    else:
        engine.say("buscando " + texto ,"Abriendo el navegador")
        engine.runAndWait()
        webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+texto)
```

or you can use dictionary mapping like this:

```
def switch(texto):
    switcher = {"nada":"Ok estare para  ti cuando me necesites", "notenecesito":"Ok estare para  ti cuando me necesites", .......}
    return switcher.get(texto, None)
```

Comment: yes its for stackoverflow code format , idk how make a case in this code

Comment: There's no switch in python like C++. You have to use if-elif-else to do so. You can create a function named switch with argument `textto` and inside that function write if-elif-else. Then you can use that function whenever you want to use switch case

Comment: funcion(textto)                                                                                                                                      if                                                                                                                                       elif                                                                                                                                else ?

Comment: yup you can do like   def switch(textto): if textto=="..":............

Comment: i need to close this funcion ?

Comment: you have to define function name it whatever you want or if you don't want to define function then just use if-elif-else directly. Also, i saw that in your if-else you have `texto==nada`. I guess your `texto` is a `string` so it should be `texto=="nada"` and same for other ones

Answer (score 0):

IndentationError: expected an indented block when try

```
def switch(texto):
    if texto == "nada":
        engine.say("Ok estare para  ti cuando me necesites")
        engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a switch statement in python, you can define a helper function like this:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

And use it in a C-like style:

```
for case in switch(texto):

    if case(nada, notenecesito):
       engine.say("Ok estare para ti cuando me necesites")
       engine.runAndWait()
       break
  
    if case(lahora):
       engine.say("La hora es"+ current_time)
       engine.runAndWait()
       print(Fore.RED+current_time)
       break
else:
    engine.say("buscando " + texto ,"Abriendo el navegador")
    engine.runAndWait()
    webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+texto)
```